# With AFNetworking 2.0 how can I test the size of my POST request with JSON?

Tags: ios, json, ios7, afnetworking-2

Not sure if this is possible but I basically need to check the size of the json in bytes or mb before it is sent to the server.

Does anyone know how to do this?

My code for sending the data to the server is:

```
 [manager POST:@"http://10.1.0.119:9000/sync" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"String Result: %@",operation.responseString);
    NSLog(@"Return JSON: %@", responseObject);
    NSLog(@"-------------------------------");
    [self executeUpdates:responseObject];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"String Result: %@",operation.responseString);
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

This code works 100% except where the JSON file is to big for the server. The server generates a 413 Error code but this does not get returned to my app on the client. My app continues as normal when the code is generated on the server and all I get back is a NULL JSON response with no error codes which I thought was weird.

I know the max size of the JSON file can be set on the server but this has obvious issues if i can't detect the error on the client side.

Hope you guys can help.

***EDIT***

The JSOn is blank because no data was send and received. But it is proper json as confirmed by jsonlint.com so how do you measure the size of the sending json? send from iPad to server? on the iPad?

JSON:

```
Sending JSON:{"teachers" : [],"syncheader" : {"servertimesync" : "","deviceid" : "4E48DBF8-F616-4AB2-A926-95F197DCCD83"},"classes" : [],"learners" : []}

Return JSON: {classes = ();learners = ();schools = (); syncheader = {deviceid = "4E48DBF8-F616-4AB2-A926-95F197DCCD83"; servertimesync = 20131129122854;}; teachers = ();}
```

Comment: And where is your JSON?

Comment: Is the JSON relevant?

Comment: If you want to know the size of the JSON, I think it's relevant. But according your code, you are not sending JSON anywhere at all. Does your question make sense?

Comment: the parameters variable is a NSDictionary of values that is sent to the sever in JSON format.

Comment: You could convert the NSDictionary to JSON string and store it in NSString then you can use `strlen([myJsonString UTF8String])` to get the size of the bytes.

Comment: @H2wk What makes you sure, these parameters are sent as JSON? Per default (in AFN), these parameters are sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert it to NSData object like this and get the total bytes from there.

```
   NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myDict options:0 error:NULL];
   NSUInteger total_bytes = [jsonData length];
```